# Spring Security: X509 (Pre-) Authentication behind Reverse Proxy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, x509, mutual-authentication

**Scenario**: The application sits behind an NGINX that terminates the TLS connection and does the mutual authentication with the client. The NGINX then forwards the client certificate in an `X-SSL-CERT` header to the spring-based application. In the application I want to access the information provided inside the certificate and also based on this create an `Authentication`.

**Current Approach**: To get it up and running, I implemented a custom `Filter` that extracts the header, parses the string into an X509 certificate, extracts the required information  into a custom `Authentication` and then uses the `SecurityContextHolder` to add the `Authentication` into the `SecurityContext`. This works and I can access the `Authentication` inside my controller methods with `@AuthenticationPrinciple` annotation.

However, while reading the documentation I felt that this approach might not be secure and also not as it is intended by spring since there is already an `X509AuthenticationFilter` to use in pre-authentication scenarios.

I then came up with the idea to just place the parsed `X509Certificate` inside the `ServletRequest` attribute and use the provided `X509AuthenticationFilter`. I quickly ran into issues, since I do not provide an `UserDetailsService`.

**Questions**:

- Is the first approach I described considered to be valid/secure?
- How can I use the `X509AuthenticationFilter` for pre-authentication use cases

  - and without providing a `UserDetailsService` since I don't require anything to get those information
- Is it secure to directly use the `SecurityContextHolder` to add my custom `Authentication` from inside the filter